# Lemma for Hurewicz Theorem (Bredon)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex, simplicial-stuff

I am trying to understand the following lemma: 
**If $f,g:I\rightarrow X$ are paths s.t. $f(1)=g(0)$ then the 1-chain $f*g-f-g$ is a boudary.**

Proof: On the standard 2-complex (should it say simplex?) $\Delta_2$ put $f$ on the edge $(e_0,e_1)$ and $g$ on the edge $(e_1,e_2)$. Then define a singular 2-simplex $\sigma:\Delta_2\rightarrow X$ **to be constant on the perpendicular lines to the edge $(e_0,e_2)$** (HOW?). **This results in the path $f*g$ being on the edge $(e_0,e_2)$** (WHY?). Therefore **$\partial \sigma=g-(f*g)+f$**

I know that $\partial \sigma=\partial^0 \sigma-\partial^1 \sigma-\partial^2 \sigma$
and that $\partial^0 \sigma(x,y,z)=\sigma(0,y,z)$
$\partial^1 \sigma(x,y,z)=\sigma(x,0,z)$
$\partial^2 \sigma(x,y,z)=\sigma(x,y,0)$

I also drew a picture and still dont get it.

This is one of three previous lemma to the Hurewicz theorem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take an equilateral triangle, and project onto one of its edges. This will produce a single edge, and follow this by the map $fg$, which will produce for you a particular $2$-chain. Restring this map to the boundary tells you that as a sum it is $f+g-fg$.

Comment: See my answer here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838755/homologous-cycle/2838806#2838806  (I don't know if you want to understand the lemma or understand a specific proof, that's why I don't know if it's a duplicate)