# Let $f,g:\Delta_1\to X$ be two paths in $X$ such that $f(e_1)=g(e_0)$. Prove that $f*g-f-g\in S_1(x)$ is a 1-boundary.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f,g:\Delta_1\to X$ be two paths in $X$ such that $f(e_1)=g(e_0)$. Prove that $f*g-f-g\in S_1(x)$ is a 1-boundary. (Here $f*g$ denotes the concatenation of paths $f$ and $g$).

I have thought about solving this exercise in the following way:

Note that $$\partial(f*g-f-g)=\partial(f*g)-\partial(f)-\partial(g)=g(e_1)-f(e_0)-(f(e_1)-f(e_0))-(g(e_1)-g(e_0))=0$$ then $$f*g-f-g\in ker(\partial:S_1(X)\to S_0(X))$$, so $$[[f*g-f-g]]\in H_1(S_*(X))=\frac{ker(\partial:S_1(X)\to S_0(X))}{Im(\partial:S_2(X)\to S_1(X))}$$.

What I want to obtain is that $[[f*g-f-g]]=[[0]]$, because if the latter is true, then $f*g-f-g-0=f*g-f-g\in Im(\partial:S_2(X)\to S_1(X))=B_1(S_1(X))$ would have to be that $f*g-f-g\in B_1(S_1(X))$ and thus $f*g-f-g$ is a 1-boundary. How can I prove then that $[[f*g-f-g]]=[[0]]$? Is what I did fine? Thank you.

Comment: You have to find a $2$-chain that maps to $f*g-f-g$ under the boundary map. Indeed, you should be able to find a single $2$-simplex $\sigma\colon \Delta_2\to X$ such that $\partial(\sigma)=f*g-f-g$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838755/homologous-cycle/2838806#2838806

Comment: @Max You should mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @PaulFrost : the question is not exactly the same, I don't know the precise policy for duplicates - is that enough similarity ?

Comment: @Max Good question, and I am not absolutely sure. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates. Anyway, your answer to the other question definitely answers the present one. In my opinion this should be sufficient. If you mark it as duplicate, then other people will also form an opinion and we see what happens.