# Constructing maps $f_k: S^1 \to S^1$ for all $k \leq 0$ such that $\deg(f_k) = k$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I think the maps should be $f_k: S^1 \to S^1: e^{2\pi i t} \mapsto e^{2 \pi i k t}$. As $f_0$ is not surjective, we chose a point (for example $-1$) not in the image of $f_0$ and then factor $f_0$ via the inclusion of $S^1 \backslash \{-1\}$ into $S^1$. As $S^1 \backslash \{-1\}$ is contractible, it has trivial homology groups, which means that $f_0^*$ is trivial. So $deg(f_0) = 0$. I can't make the inductive step work. Is there maybe a more direct approach?

Comment: What kind of homology are you using? Are you defining "degree" in terms of the induced map on homology? Do you have an explicit description of a generator of $H_1(S^1)$? Can you see what its image should be under $(f_k)_*$?

Comment: @William Singular homology (until just now I did not know there were multiple types), the degree is defined as $f^*(1)$ under the identification $H_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and any homeomorphism $\Delta^1 \to S^1$ is a generator. Its image under $(f_k)_*$ is then looping $\Delta^1$ $k$ times over $S^1$. I don't see why the chain of your answer generates $H_1(S^1)$. Other than that your answer is clear. Can you give a proof or reference to one?

Comment: I added some more explanation for that point, I hope I sorted it out. Also, did you mean to say $k\leq 0$ in your question or did you want $k\geq 0$?

Comment: @William Thank you it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's geometrically slightly simpler when $k>0$ so consider this case first. Consider the singular $1$-chain $\varphi_{k,j}\colon \Delta^1 \to S^1$ for $0\leq j < k$ defined by

$$\varphi_{k,j}(t_0, t_1) = e^{2\pi i (t_0 + j)/k}$$

which is an arc from $e^{2\pi i j/k}$ to $e^{2\pi i (j + 1)/k}$. I claim that for each $k>0$ the $1$-chain $\sum_{j = 0} ^{k - 1} \varphi_{k,j}$ generates $H_1(S^1)$, because the sum of composable paths is homologous to their composition (see for example [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838755/homologous-cycle/2838806#2838806)) so for each $k>0$ the sum is homologous to $\varphi_{1, 0}$, which is the path that travels counter-clockwise once around the circle.

The pushforward under $f_k$ is given by

$$(f_k)_*(\varphi_{k,j})(t_0, t_1) = (e^\frac{2\pi i (t_0 + j)}{k})^k = e^{2\pi i (t_0 + j)} = e^{2\pi i t_0} = \varphi_{1,0}(t_0, t_1)$$

where the second-last equation is because $j$ is an integer. Therefore $(f_k)_*[\varphi_{0,1}] = (f_k)_* [\sum_{j = 0} ^{k - 1} \varphi_{k,j}] = k[\varphi_{1, 0}]$, so $f_k$ has degree $k$.

The argument for $k<0$ is similar, but in this case $(f_k)_*[\varphi_{k, j}] = -[\varphi_{1,0}]$